# GridSearchCV scoring

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

```
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=BernoulliRBM(),param_grid=parameters,verbose=3,n_jobs=-1,refit=True)
```

I am getting the following error-

```
TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator BernoulliRBM() does not.
```

BernoulliRBM does have a method `score_samples(X)`, but how do I pass that to the scoring parameter of gridsearchcv? I can pass the general scoring metrics like F1 score etc according to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter.
But how do I pass that method?

Comment: Not sure if that's going to work but *if* `score_samples(X)` produces the scoring you need you can create a subclass of `BernoulliRBM` class and define a new method `score()` that returns `return self.score_samples(X)`. And then call this new class as estimator.

Answer (score 0):

When scoring, `GridSearchCV` literally calls the `score` method of the model. As you can see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.BernoulliRBM.html#sklearn.neural_network.BernoulliRBM.score_samples), `BernoulliRBM` does not have a method that exactly matches `.score()`.

You can either pass it a string to call another predefined scoring metric from [this list](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values) (like you mentioned) or you can define your own scoring method and pass it as a callable. The documentation for the second option is [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object).

Your classifier's scoring method returns the pseudo likelihood of `X`. Unfortunately, there's not a pre-defined scoring for that, so you will have to define it yourself.

The quickest way to do this is to define a method `self.score(X, y)` that passes `X` to `score_samples` and use that output to compare against `y`.

Comment: If there are no restrictions, I would suggest you specify the parameter scoring in gridsearchcv.